# MQTT Can broker send any message to client before server disconnect the existing client?

Tags: mqtt

MQTT Broker can disconnect the existing client if the following condition is came up.

> http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718090
>
> 1. If the ClientId represents a Client already connected to the Server then the Server MUST disconnect the existing Client
>      [MQTT-3.1.4-2].

At this time, can broker send any specific message excluding "DISCONNECT" to client before server disconnect the existing client ?

Comment: What and why do you want to send something else?

Answer (score 1):

Most brokers are going to follow the spec, if you want one to do something different then you will have to either write your own or modify one of the open source versions.